# Configure Fail2ban to ignore local (NAT) IPs

Tags: linux, security, login, fail2ban

How can I configure **fail2ban** to always allow attempts from the local/NAT ips (ie `192.168.1.*`).  I have tried putting the following entry into `/etc/fail2ban/jail.conf`:

```
[DEFAULT]

# "ignoreip" can be an IP address, a CIDR mask or a DNS host
ignoreip = 127.0.0.1 192.168.1.*
bantime  = 600
maxretry = 3
```

but upon restart I had the following warning in my `/var/log/fail2ban.log`

> WARNING Unable to find a corresponding
>   IP address for 192.168.1.*

What's the correct configuration for what I'm trying to do?

Please note that I still wish local host (`127.0.0.1`) to be exempted as well.

> Ubuntu 9.04

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Shouldn't you add `192.168.1.0/24` instead of `192.168.1.*` ?

Comment: @emgee how can i add single ip address for allow ??? like 123.245.245.245 (for example)

Comment: @Kumar well just add `123.245.245.245`